# Can WCF service that is hosted inside Windows Service be reachable from the other domain(any machine on the internet)?

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-services

If WCF Service is hosted by Windows Service, can any machine from the internet make a request to this WCF Service ?

Does it even matter who hosts the WCF service? Or it doesn't matter and the only thing that matters is that WCF can handle http requests?

The thing that confused me is that Troelsen in his book wrote: "If you build an in-house WCF application, another alternative you have is to host your WCF Service Library from within a dedicated Windows service". So, if it's "in-house", it would be reachable only in the same domain? Why so?..

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can allow access to a WCF service hosted via a windows service.

Obviously, this will entail modifying your network/firewall settings and ultimately, may be better suited to run on a standard HTTP interface (IIS).

Comment: Thanks.
Do you mean that if WCF service is hosted inside IIS, then there is no need to configure Firewall settings, but if WCF service is hosted inside Windows Service, then Firewall settings probably should be changed to allow all requests?

Comment: I mean that it is probably easier to configure your firewall to allow connections to IIS and host the service through this.